# Euclidian GCD in Language Assembly. Code not working

Tags: visual-studio, x86

I am writing this Euclidian GCD program in Language assembly and I think I know what is the problem but I don't know how to fix it. The thing is I am calling GCD recursively from within and every time I call GCD the ESP moves 4 bytes down because it has to store the return address on the stack with each call. Therefore, my EBP will point 4 bytes down from the previous call. Can someone help me fix this code?

```
;Kirtan Patel
;Create a Euclidian GCD Program
;10/30/2014

.586

.MODEL FLAT

.STACK 4096

.DATA
numberm DWORD 14
numbern DWORD 10
.CODE
main PROC
         push numbern ;push 10 onto the stack
         push numberm ;push 14 onto the stack
         call gcd     ; call gcd function
         add esp, 8   ;pop off the parameters from the stack.
         ret          ;exit the program
main ENDP

gcd PROC
        push ebp      ;push ebp onto the stack to preserve previous contents of ebp 
        mov ebp, esp  ;copy esp to ebp to access the parameters 10 and 14 later on
        push edx      ;save the registers 
        push ebx
        push ecx
        mov ecx, DWORD PTR[ebp+12] ;copy 10 to ecx
        cmp ecx, 0                 ;compare to see if the divisor is zero
        jnz recur                  ;if it is not zero then recursively call gcd
        mov eax, DWORD PTR[ebp+8]  ; if it zero then copy 14 to eax and return
        pop ecx                    ;restore the contents of registers before exiting the function
        pop ebx
        pop edx
        pop ebp
        ret
recur: mov eax, DWORD PTR[ebp+8]   ;copy 14 to eax
       cdq                         ; prepare the edx register for division to store the remainder
       div ecx                     ;eax/ecx (14/10)
       mov DWORD PTR[ebp+12], edx  ;copy the remainder into numbern on the stack
       mov DWORD PTR[ebp+8], ecx   ;copy the new divisor into numberm on the stack
       pop ecx                     ;restore registers
       pop ebx
       pop edx
       pop ebp
       call gcd                    ;recursively call gcd

gcd ENDP


END
```

Comment: I think commenting the code with what you're _intending_ the code to do might help.

Comment: Ok let me try to comment it. Thanks

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I have commented it.

Comment: What happens when your recursive call to gcd (`call gcd`) returns? Seems it'll fall off the end of the earth.

Comment: When I call gcd again it returns the contents of EAX

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters on the stack. Use [this C program](http://www.cquestions.com/2008/01/c-program-to-find-gcd-of-number-using.html) as a prototype for your recursive function, and use the techniques [described here](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH11/CH11-4.html) to pass your parameters on each recursive call.

```c
int findgcd(int x,int y){
     while(x!=y){
          if(x>y)
              return findgcd(x-y,y);
          else
             return findgcd(x,y-x);
     }
     return x;
}
```

Comment: I understand the Euclidian algorithm. My only problem is that with every recursive call the return address of the previous call is added on the stack hence accessing the numbern and numberm parameters pushed on the stack by the main method is impossible.

Comment: Did you read [the post I linked about how to properly pass parameters on the stack](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/CH11/CH11-4.html)?

Comment: I read it but there is too information in there which I didn't understand any.